# Can I push down a comment in Teiid to the source query?

Tags: jboss, teiid

Is it possible to push down comments to the source database query?

Given example Teiid query:

```
select /* 'request_id' */ columnA, sum(columnB)
from tableA
```

I'd like to see the comment pushed down to the source database so that I can capture the request_id in the logs. I've looked at source hints, but have not had any luck getting those pushed down to the source query either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/master/content/reference/JDBC_Translators.html and search for UseCommentsInSourceQuery

Comment: Could you provide an example of where this is set? I've tried many things and still can't get it to work.

Comment: `<translator name="oracle-override" type="oracle">
     <property name="UseCommentsInSourceQuery" value="true"/>
     <property name="CommentFormat" value="/*requestid:\{1}.\{2}*/"/>
</translator>` if you are using the XML based VDB, a DDL based VDB will be represented little differently

Comment: This didn't work: `<model name="Tbl"><source connection-jndi-name="java:/java:/Tbl" name="Tbl" translator-name="impala_overrides"/><metadata type="DDL-FILE">/sources/detail/Tbl.ddl</metadata></model><model name="Vw" type="VIRTUAL"><property name="imports" value="Tbl"/><metadata type="DDL-FILE">/views/Vw.ddl</metadata></model><translator description="" name="impala_overrides" type="impala"><property name="UseCommentsInSourceQuery" value="true"/><property name="CommentFormat" value="/*requestid:\{1}.\{2}*/"/></translator>` But I am also looking to pass custom comment to source. It gets stripped.

Comment: I believe custom comments can be only be sent on DirectQueryExecutions as there is no place to define this on a View transformation. Of course, you can extend the translator also to add custom ones. We have done this for Oracle as shown here https://github.com/teiid/teiid/blob/master/connectors/jdbc/translator-jdbc/src/main/java/org/teiid/translator/jdbc/oracle/OracleExecutionFactory.java#L598-L610, unfortunately, this comment style does not apply to all, if you think certain format applies to Impla open a JIRA we can fix it

Comment: Thanks, Ramesh! I will give it a try.